# Is there always a prime number in the form of $4k+1$ between $[n, 2n]$ for every large enough $n$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there always a prime number in the form of $4k+1$ between $[n, 2n]$ for every large enough $n$?

I guess it is known as a classical result. Is there any reference for it?

Thanks!

Comment: I would call [Bertrand's postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_postulate) a classical result, but I haven't heard of your variation (not saying it doesn't exist!).

Comment: I found this note(http://math.bard.edu/cullinan/papers/prescribed_submitted.pdf)  which seems to give a positive answer to my question. Thanks!

Comment: One can get it from the fact if $\pi_1(x)$ is the number of primes of your form $\le x$, then $\pi_1(x)$ is asymptotically $\frac{x}{2\log x}$. That's undoubtedly overkill. But I have not seen a variant of the usual elementary proofs of the Bertrand postulate that deals with your qurstion.

Comment: Is there a reference for how to derive \pi_1 ? Thanks!

Comment: You derive it from Dirichlet's Theorem on primes in arithmetic progression, you have $\pi_1(x)=\pi(x)/\varphi(4)$